# Como impedir que uma aplicação React Native retorne ao clicar no BackButton usando React Navigation

Tags: react, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-fluid-transitions

Olá, estou criando uma aplicação em React Native, e para as navegações eu tenho trabalhado com o plugin React Navigation. A estrutura do meu projeto está assim:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { FluidNavigator } from 'react-navigation-fluid-transitions';

// tela de splash
export default SplashScreen extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount = () => 
    setTimeout(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login'), 500);

  render = () => 
    <View>
    <Text>SplashScreen</Text>
  </View>;
}

// tela de login de usuario
export default LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  goToDashboard = () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard');
  goToRegister = () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Register');
  render = () =>
    <View>
      <Text>LoginScreen</Text>
      <Button onPress={goToDashboard} title="Sign in" />
      <Button onPress={goToRegister} title="Sign up" />
    </View>
  }
}

// tela de registro de usuario
export default RegisterScreen extends React.Component {
  render = () => <View><Text>RegisterScreen</Text></View>;
}

// tela de dashboard (após o usuário estar logado)
export default DashboardScreen extends React.Component {
  render = () => <View><Text>DashboardScreen</Text></View>;
}

// navigator contendo as telas
const Navigator = FluidNavigator({
  Splash: { screen: SplashScreen },
  Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
  Register: { screen: RegisterScreen },
  Dashboard: { screen: DashboardScreen }
})

export default App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <View><Navigator/></View>
  }      
}
```

Meu problema está nas navegações. Quando o usuário clica no botão voltar, ele vai para a tela anterior e isso me complica... eu preciso que a navegação seja na seguinte relação:

- `SplashScreen => LoginScreen`
- `LoginScreen <=> RegisterScreen`
- `LoginScreen  => DashboardScreen`
- `RegisterScreen => DashboardScreen`

Eu até tentei resetar o index usando o `NavigationActions` mas isso atrapalha as animações que estão na tela (por causa do `react-navigation-fluid-transitions`).

Também tentei bloquear o evento do BackButton assim como em alguns tutoriais, só que se eu bloqueio ele na tela de Screen, ele passa a dar pau em todas as telas, impedindo que eu consiga voltar para a tela de Login na tela de Register e consequentemente para as outras telas que virão na aplicação.

O que eu preciso fazer para que eu impeça (dentro da tela que eu quero impedir) para que ela não possa voltar até 'X' tela?

Comment: Você já tentou setar em cada página o retorno que cada uma deve ter?

Comment: não entendi... poderia me dar um exemplo? sou novo com react-native e realmente não consegui ver o que me falou...

Comment: Então eu costumo determinar de maneira direta a rota que deve seguir ao clicar no botão de retorno. Você pode fazer adicionando no construtor da sua página o seguinte código: `BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
      Actions.rota_que_deseja();
      return true;
    }); `

Comment: eu tentei fazer algo assim, mas se eu faço 1 vez, a função padrão de voltar buga e não funciona normalmente. Sibem que eu poderia forçar a navegação a voltar com um `this.props.navigation.navigatePrev()`

Comment: Funcionou utilizando  o `navigatePrev()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com base no que o @sant0will disse nas respostas, eu consegui "resolver" o problema ao adicionar em todas as telas um tratamento específico para o BackHandler, assim:

```js
export default SplashScreen extends React.Component {
  //...
  componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => { return true; });
  }
}

// tela de login de usuario
export default LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  //...
  componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => { return true; });
  }
}

// tela de registro de usuario
export default RegisterScreen extends React.Component {
  //...
  componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => { 
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
      return true; 
    });
  }
}

// tela de dashboard (após o usuário estar logado)
export default DashboardScreen extends React.Component {
  //...
  componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => { return true; });
  }
}
```

> Sinceramente não gostei de resolver assim porque me cheira a "recurso técnico" mas como funcionou e é como vai ficar...

Comment: Boaaa, que bom que funcionou.

Comment: valei parceiro! =D

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que sei no react navigation existe uma função própria que se chama goBack que volta a tela anterior, simplesmente você irá importar o react-navigation/native, e usar o useNavigation do mesmo, e assim usar o onPress dentro do seu "botão"
Exemplo:

```
<TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
            >
                <Text>
                    Voltar
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).